# Fastapi token returns None in jwt authentication?

Tags: python, jwt, fastapi

In fastapi jwt implementAation token returns null.
dependency functions

```
reuseable_oauth = OAuth2PasswordBearer(
    tokenUrl="/login",
    scheme_name="JWT",
    auto_error = False
)


async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(reuseable_oauth)):
    try:
        print(token)
        payload = jwt.decode(
            token, JWT_SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM]
        )
        token_data = payload['sub']
        
        if datetime.fromtimestamp(token_data.exp) < datetime.now():
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="Token expired",
                headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
            )
    except(jwt.JWTError, ValidationError):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
            detail="Could not validate credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
        
    user: Union[dict[str, Any], None] = db.get(token_data.sub, None)
    
    
    if user is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail="Could not find user",
        )
     return user
    
class TokenSchema(BaseModel):
   accesstoken : str = Field(...)
```

routing functions

```
@app.post('/login', summary="Create access and refresh tokens for user", response_model=TokenSchema)
async def login(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    user = db.get(form_data.username, None)
    if user is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="Incorrect email or password"
        )

    hashed_pass = user['password']
    if not verify_password(form_data.password, hashed_pass):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="Incorrect email or password"
        )
    
    return {
        "accesstoken": create_access_token(user['email'])
    }



from app.deps import get_current_user

@app.get('/me', summary='Get details of currently logged in user', response_model=UserOut)
async def get_me(user: User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    return user
```

I first make a post to /login and then get request to /me. However, token in get_current_user funtion is null in the first place, which in turn gives further errors, which I also check in print(token) line.
What could be the reason and how to solve them?
I refer to [jwt-authentication](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-jwt-authentication-in-fastapi/)

Comment: What kind of request are you submitting to the `/me` endpoint? What headers are present? i.e. how are you including the token that should get decoded?